# Error: Job 'bigquery-data-280611.job_LppnDbYTUiQeRVnbwRkQjPGrSLFj.US' failed x Unrecognized name: Especie_Docum at [2:8] [invalidQuery]

Tags: google-bigquery

When calling the function **bigrquery::bq_project_query(projectid, sql_query)** in rstudio, I get the following error

Error: Job 'bigquery-data-280611.job_LppnDbYTUiQeRVnbwRkQjPGrSLFj.US' failed
x Unrecognized name: Especie_Docum at [2:8] [invalidQuery]
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Looks like you have a problem with the SQL query you wrote and passed in the sql_query variable.  Can you share that query?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.